# How to plot Ho v Hs in dartR?

Tags: r

I have SNP dataset from Dartseq (148 individuals and 12,123 loci).
I am analysing it in dartR.
I have calculated both Ho (gl.Ho(gl)) and Hs (gl.Hs(gl)) in dartR. 
I want to plot Ho v Hs. 
How do I do this please?
I think it should be so easy, but I have made no progress. 
I know the following:

`head(Ho)`

```
39086092-43-A/T 39030115-36-G/T 39036131-46-C/T 39031387-28-T/A  39043148-8-C/T 
0.006944444     0.000000000     0.014184397     0.076388889     0.007246377 
 39052543-5-C/T 
0.000000000
```

`str(Ho) # # Shows the structure of the data`

```
Named num [1:12119] 0.00694 0 0.01418 0.07639 0.00725 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12119] "39086092-43-A/T" "39030115-36-G/T" "39036131-46-C/T" "39031387-28-T/A" ...
```

`class(Ho) # numeric`

[1] "numeric"

`head(Hs)`

```
39086092-43-A/T 39030115-36-G/T 39036131-46-C/T 39031387-28-T/A  39043148-8-C/T 
0.006920332     0.013888210     0.014083799     0.192105517     0.049438143 
 39052543-5-C/T 
0.027391975
```

PS. Edited this morning after I found a post on Markdown help. It is now easier to read at least.

Comment: Can you not just do `plot(Ho, Hs)`?

Comment: Thank you so much @mickey. That worked.